# C++ insert numbers until certain symbol

Tags: c++, arrays, variables

I tried to write a code that asked me to input numbers one by one and when a certain char was inserted ( in this case 'x' ) it would stop the loop. But when I insert that char it starts spamming me with "Insert Number" . I think that the fault is that I'm trying to insert a char in an int array, but I can't think a way around it.

```
long int numbers[100]={0};
char h='y';
int index=0;
do
{
    cout << "Insert Number : ";
    cin >> numbers[index];
    h=(char)numbers[index];
    index++;
}
while(h!='x');
```

Comment: read a string, then you'll know what to do.

Comment: What does spam mean in this case? Do you run into an endless loop?

Comment: You can't read a character into an integer.  Try doing it the other way around.

Comment: Also: What do you suppose a literal `x` in the input is converted to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write a loop as:

```
while(cin >> numbers[index]) 
   index++;
```

It will read all the integers, untill you enter some invalid input, be it `'x'` or any other character. Now if you want to skip all invalid inputs and continue reading integers (which might be after invalid inputs), and want to consider only `'x'` to exit from the loop, then wrap the above loop with another loop as:

```
char ch;
do
{
   while(cin >> numbers[index]) 
       index++;
   cin.clear(); //clear the error flags, so you can use cin to continue reading
   cin >> ch; //read the invalid character
} while(ch != 'x');
```

One piece of advice:  prefer using `std::vector<long int>` over `long int numbers[100]`. What if user entered more than `100` integers, then your program will be corrupted.

Comment: @This has undefined behavior (but is likely to loop forever); once the inner loop fails, `cin` is in an error state, which must be cleared before any further input will be accepted.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Thanks. I forgot that. :-)

Answer (score 2):

This happens because 'x' is not a number and `cin >> numbers[index];` operation fails, without consuming that data. So the loop continues, gets the same `x`, fails again and everything starts all over again. You can check for result of input operation, something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    long int numbers[100]={0};
    char h='y';
    int index=0;
    do
    {
        cout << "Insert Number : ";
        if (cin >> numbers[index])
        {
            h=(char)numbers[index];
            index++;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Hey, that was not a number! Bye." << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    while(h!='x');
}
```

Comment: The way you've written this, it will exit if the user types in 120 (since casting 120 to a char gives 'x').

Comment: @EdwardLoper: True. But I didn't write it :) All this story with 'x' is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're trying to read in an integer, any character that isn't a digit can't be converted to a number and will jam up the input - you'll get an error and the bad character will not be removed from the stream. The next time you try to read you'll get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect a number or a string, always read the input as a string, and try converting it to a number afterwards if the string isn't "x":

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>    

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<long int> numbers;
    std::string line;
    while(std::getline(std::cin, line) && line != "x") {
        std::istringstream input(line);
        long int value; 
        // Check that there is only a number with nothing else after
        if((input >> value) && input.get() == std::char_traits<char>::eof()) {
            numbers.push_back(value);
        } else {
            std::cout << "Invalid Entry, please retry" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    //...

    return 0;
}
```